# Плавный переход между видео в Mplayer

Tags: linux

Имеется плейлист с видео для Mplayer, который отлично отрабатывает.
Можно ли сделать переход от одного файла к другому через фейд (уводить в черный, а потом возвращать)? Как это можно сделать из консоли?

Answer (score 1):

насколько мне известно, программа *mplayer* не обладает такой (*crossfade*) функциональностью.

проверить можно с помощью поискового запроса "mplayer video crossfade".